# URL rewrite word

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a fairly simple problem which I can't figure out.

Here is my .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$1
```

This results in URL's such as www.example.com/articles/article-name
What I'd like is to change the 'articles' in the rule, to the name of the current URL.

For example from:

```
www.example.com/articles/article-name
```

To:

```
www.example.com/blog/article-name
www.example.com/gallery/article-name
```

I am currently writing links as:

```
<a href="articles/$articleName">
```

I have changed it to the following, but can't get the .htaccess working with it:

```
<a href="$pageNoExtension/$articleName">
```

Thanks in advance and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php?article=$2
```

Happy new year to you too :)

Comment: the php file is always called articles.php

Comment: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article_type=$1&article=$2   then??

Comment: I was thinking RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$2, this WORKS but results in other files not found, for example the articles work but the login.php in the includes folder isn't found.

Comment: aww then the problem is that you're not detecting the existing files first, you should add 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
before the rewriterule. first of them detects existing file and stops if it exists, and the second one is for directories...

Comment: sorry it's still having problems accessing files in different folders. The links work perfectly, but 'cannot find' files in different directories

Comment: This is what i have atm: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$2

Comment: and what kind of url can't you access in case of your rewriterule?

Comment: for example: www.example.com/includes/login.php, www.example.com/articles.php and other files in the same directory all work fine

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the problem as I just tested it on my host and it works fine when i request like includes/asd.php. try with this htaccess: http://cs16.us/testht (I tried with this one and it works)

Comment: umm.. are you sure you really have the correct file in the correct directory? or maybe you're using subdirectory as document root? In the latter case you should set RewriteBase /my_subdirectory_name/

Comment: im using htaccess to rewrite several urls, all located in the document root :/